# How can I stop PyCharm from (incorrectly) autoformatting rst files?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I writing Python documentation in rst files, used as input for Sphinx generation. When I ask PyCharm to do a code cleanup, or commit files, it cleans Python files (as expected) but also cleans rst files.

Unfortunately, these rst cleans are incorrect (I suspect it is treating them as though they are Python files). For example...

```
Title
=====

.. automodule:: module_name
   :members:
```

gets corrected to...

```
Title
=====

.. automodule:: module_name
:members:
```

How can I stop PyCharm cleaning these files, but still clean Python files? (Ideally, it would clean the rst files using an ReStructuredText linter, but failing that, I just want it to ignore them.)

Comment: Check your file type associations to see if rst is in the list of files to associate with Python processing -> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/file-types.html. Also, you might have a separate plugin for rst files that are doing the association as well? But that is also a wild guess on my part.

Comment: @idjaw nope, rst files have their own file association - I have the two default rst plugins loaded